# How is Apache Thrift scalable?

Tags: scalability, thrift

In their [website](https://thrift.apache.org/) Apache Thrift is introduced as

> software framework, for scalable cross-language services
>   development...

but I couldn't find what makes it scalable. So my question is what makes it scalable? Does just using Thrift make your application scalable? If not, how do I use thrift in a scalable way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

["Scalability"](http://searchdatacenter.techtarget.com/definition/scalability), in this context, means the ability to partition the application in as many or few pieces, using as few or as as many different processors, as necessary.  The same app can be "built out" simply by adding hardware.

From the Thrift white paper:

> https://thrift.apache.org/static/files/thrift-20070401.pdf
>
> Thrift has enabled Facebook to build scalable backend services
> efficiently by enabling engineers to divide and conquer. Application
> developers can focus on application code without worrying about the
> sockets layer. We avoid duplicated work by writing buffering and I/O
> logic in one place, rather than interspersing it in each application.

Comment: When you say `partition the application in as many or few pieces` do you mean that different parts of the application can reside on different machines and communicate using api calls? Is that how Thrift is scalable?